# Remote access of a site in IIS Express while debugging

Tags: iis

I'm developing a .NET web forms site inside a VMWare Windows 10 virtual machine, with Visual Studio 2019.
Inside the VM the site works.

Now I need to run the site in debug, but access the site from the REAL PC ... I've tried everything, but I always obtain a "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.".
Inside the same virtual machine I installed the site in IIS, port 81, and I can access it from the real PC. The difference seems to be where the site are hosted: I can access the site hosted by IIS but I can'T access the site when I'm running the developing version from Visual Stidio on IIS Express.
Of course I need this to debug.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems you don’t understand the difference between iis and iis express, iis is not equivalent to iis express. [Secrets Behind Visual Studio IIS Express Integration](https://lextm.medium.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b).

Comment: What should I understand from the link you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug your website, it's fine.

**1. You need to publish your project with debug mode.**

**2. Run the vs2019 with administrator, and attach to running processes to debug your project.**

**Test Steps**

*1. publish project*

[image]

*2. open vs2019*

[image]

*3. attach to iis running process*

[image]

Press ctrl key to select below two options.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw with Firefox from outside the virtual machine I can access a published site insite the virtual machine (IIS). I have an old version of this site published inside the virtual machine. I will try your tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: I confirm your suggestion works well.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to install our free extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

What it does is proxy requests to IIS Express, so you don't need to change any configuration or use admin privilege.  Also it can enable tunneling through your firewall if you like, to enable access from the web.